# zsh: command not found: nx

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to create a library in Angular using `nx g @nrwl/angular:lib shared` but it keep giving me error `zsh: command not found: nx`. All I did was before just create a angular project.
I try using this: `npm install -g nx` so maybe it install `nx` and it works, but I still keep getting the same error.

How can I fix this? I am using Mac.
If any questions or information needed please feel free to leave the comment down below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either you don't have refreshed your `zsh` paths, which can be fixed by opening a new terminal or type

> rehash

in the prompt.

If this doesn't work then `nx` isn't globally installed on your machine. You have to type
`npm run nx [your command]` instead of just "`nx`" to use it, so in your case:

```
npm run nx -- g @nrwl/angular:lib shared
```

Sources: https://nx.dev/latest/angular/cli/overview#installing-the-cli

Comment: The second option worked. I was wondering how can I install it globally, so I don't have to type run?

Comment: Also, can you answer my this question as well? Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068124/how-to-create-an-application-in-angular-project

Answer (score 17):

`sudo npm install -g nx` fixed, `sudo` might be needed...

Comment: Doing sudo npm i is usally a bad idea. There are many reasons like you can potentially mess up your environment, and it's usually a pain to fix if that happens. There are also security concerns. There was a trend where malicious packages were created with misspellings of well known packages like `loadash` (instead of properly spelled `lodash`). At the very least I'd recommend you try first without `sudo`. Here is an [article with more info](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3)

Comment: Agree with @FelipeCenteno, sudo here is not recommended.

Answer (score 16):

Do we really need to install `@nrwl/cli` ?

Just installing the `nx` resolve the issue for me

```
sudo npm install -g nx@latest
```

Comment: In 2023 this should be the correct answer! As you can see [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/9399).

Answer (score 14):

Try this: Install it globally by below command 100% will work

```
sudo npm i -g @nrwl/cli
```

remove -g if you don't want to install globally.

Comment: Doing sudo npm i is usally a bad idea. There are many reasons like you can potentially mess up your environment, and it's usually a pain to fix if that happens. There are also security concerns. There was a trend where malicious packages were created with misspellings of well known packages like `loadash` (instead of properly spelled `lodash`). At the very least I'd recommend you try first without `sudo`. Here is an [article with more info](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3)

Answer (score 3):

Installing the nrwl cli globally should do the trick, you'll need to enter the super user mode to do it.

```html
sudo npm i -g @nrwl/cli
```

Alternative solutions can be found on the guide on the Nx Website here

https://nx.dev/l/a/tutorial/01-create-application

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yarn global add @nrwl/cli
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing at a `yarn` variant but it seems OP was asking for `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove node_modules and reinstall dependencies via

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn install
```

this works for me