# nx command not found on gitlab-runner

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, npm-install, gitlab-runner

I have installed nx globally using Sudo

```
sudo npm install -g nx
```

and it works fine, but sometimes it gives the below error

```
bash: line 136: nx: command not found
```

After retry, it works fine again.

Comment: I have the same issue and never found why, but i didn't really take the time to found a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if adding [`nrwl/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nrwl/cli) would help, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69505708/6309):

```
sudo npm i -g @nrwl/cli
```

And check if, in case of error, the `$PATH` value as seen in the GitLab runner, to understand why it would not see `nx`.
Using `npm run nx` as an alternative to `nx` coud be a workaround in that case.